# How do nested variables within the .env file work in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Under the "Nesting Variables" section in Codeigniter4 site:

"To save on typing, you can reuse variables that you’ve already specified in the file by wrapping the variable name within ${...}"
[link to CI nesting Variables section](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/configuration.html)

example in the documentation:

```
BASE_DIR="/var/webroot/project-root"

CACHE_DIR="${BASE_DIR}/cache"

TMP_DIR="${BASE_DIR}/tmp"
```

I was trying to use the following

```
app.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/'

google.redirect = ${app.baseURL}Google
```

However, it's assigning it as a literal when print_r($_ENV)

`[google.redirect] => ${app.baseURL}Google`

I've tried using non-namespaced keys including BASE_DIR (per the example) and it keeps printing as a literal.

What's strange - When I use the following:

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development

google.redirect = ${CI_ENVIRONMENT}Google
```

The result when print_r is:

```
[CI_ENVIRONMENT] => development

[google.redirect] => developmentGoogle
```

My question is - What am I doing incorrectly and/or how should these be set/used correctly?

According to the documentation, I should be able to use any key within the .env file that was already assigned using

${somekeyinthisfile}

Comment: You are using it correctly. I've been having a poke around and it appears that the regex doesn't allow for . (dots). I'm still looking.

Comment: Even without using the dots - I still can't get it to work  sans CI_ENVIRONMENT.

using
x = test
somerandomvariablename = foo

It still reads as a literal:
[google.redirect] => ${x}GoogleLogin
[google.redirect] => ${somerandomvariablename}GoogleLogin

Comment: Ah ha so I was wondering why I wasn't getting the same thing... Now I've come up with a New Library file to override the existing system\config\DotEnv.php methods of load() and resolveNestedVariables(). So how much pain are you in with this not working at the moment?

Comment: Not too much pain. 
I'm coming over from CI3 and was just playing around with CI4 to start the process of migrating my sites. If it's just waiting till there's a fix in the main code - I can wait. I'm not in any hurry.

Comment: Ok - Well I've got a 4am "patch" that makes it all sing and dance but it involves either altering the DotEnv.php core file directly, which in this case might not be a bad thing... The alternative is creating a new DotEnv.php that just overrides those methods... So the ole - change things without changing the system files directly. Both are fun :) So that was a fun little debug session :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of looking, there is a more recent file up at
https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/Config/DotEnv.php
with all the "other" changes...

**This was a Bug Fix.** So get that file and you will be good to go.

> *I am pretty sure that the intention wasn't to allow app.xxx settings to be used as variables as the documentation clearly shows, by not
> showing them being used. ( yes its 6am now ...)*

BUT it is your code to do with as you please...So if you want to use app.xxx as variables...

**The Only Thing missing is the DOT (.) in the regex**

If you look on **Line 272 - system/Config/DotEnv.php inside method resolveNestedVariables()** and add a . (dot) into the regex, that will make all your app.things work.

```
  $value = preg_replace_callback(
     '/\${([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)}/',
     function ($matchedPatterns) use ($loader) {
```

I have added a dot (.) at the end of the `[a-zA-Z0-9_`

So
`'/\${([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)}/',`

becomes

```
'/\${([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)}/',
```